# Cookie setting to open popup only on first initial page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm running a website where I need an Adult Warning popup to allow the visitor to either exit or enter the site.

I'm running a wordpress site in conjunction with this plugin: EMC2 POPUP DISCLAIMER that almost works perfectly however the only issue is that it popups on each individual initial page load.

I need the plugin to only popup on the first initial page load then once the visitor clicks the enter button the popup will not reappear until the cookie life has expired.

I found the javascript cookie code:

```
(function($) {
$.cookie = function(key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value === null || value === undefined)) {
        options = $.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var decode = options.raw ? function(s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;

    var pairs = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = 0, pair; pair = pairs[i] && pairs[i].split('='); i++) {
        if (decode(pair[0]) === key) return decode(pair[1] || ''); // IE saves cookies with empty string as "c; ", e.g. without "=" as opposed to EOMB, thus pair[1] may be undefined
    }
    return null;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone explain how the cookie setting is appearing on each page load and how to modify it so the popup is only on the first initial page load?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see docs https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Thank you for the reference charlietfl. I have looked it over and I am still not sure how to make the modification. Under usage I do see it's stating to use `$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });` to create an expiring cookie across the entire site. At line 31 of the script I see `options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',` where there is no input inside the single quotes at the end of the line. To properly set the sitewide expiring cookie would and the slash inside the single quote's so it would be `options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '/',`

Comment: suggest read about cookies here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie  Explains about defaults